# Avast detects SciPy as a virus?

Tags: python, scipy, antivirus

I installed scipy from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/). While downloading, avast detected the scipy downloaded as malicious (the 64 bit one for python 3.4). I turned off safe guard because I was sure it wasn't malicious, I've used this site for tons of python modules and never had an issue. But, when I was using the module for linear interpolation, Avast detected the same 'virus'. Is this real or false positive?

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/OSCAAR/OSCAAR/issues/94

Comment: Yeah, I found that too. I think it is indeed related, meaning it's a virus, but googling something like 'scipy avast' or something similar leads to almost no results besides this, which made me want to post this.

Answer (score 0):

From the site:

> The files are unofficial (meaning: informal, unrecognized, personal, unsupported, no warranty, no liability, provided "as is") and made available for testing and evaluation purposes.

I doubt that it is actually a malicious Python Module.  I'm pretty sure that Avast thinks it is just a malicious "script" since it has never encountered it and isn't that popular (since from my experience most Python users are using some form of *nix and probably not running an antivirus).  If you have access to the source code you may be able to view it yourself just to double check.

Comment: Well one guy makes all of those files, so I don't think he'd put a virus in one for any reason. I'm sure it's a false positive, unless his site was compromised

Comment: @Lillz Yeah, I'd definitely have to agree with you on that, sorry I wasn't more help!

Comment: Oh you're fine! I was just curious if any one else was getting it too and just confirming my false positive hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because it isn't certified through any major software company, "unofficial". Scan the file once downloaded just to be on the safe side though.